# Manipulating Shopping Cart Rules

Tags: php, magento

I’m just confused about how the shopping cart rule works. I have a promo, buy 5 get 5% discount. Under my settings, I have set the discount to be percentage, the discount amount is 5 while the maximum is amount is 9. I’ve also set the discount qty step to 5.

Then under the conditions, I’ve set Quantity in cart is equals or less than 9.

From my understanding this should mean any item as long as there are 5 or more (max 9) on my shopping cart, I should get a 5% discount. However, after performing some tests, I noticed that this is only applied if for example I buy something like so:

```
Item A Quantity - 5
```

If I buy something like:

```
Item A Quantity - 2 
Item B Quantity - 3 
Item C Quantity - 1
```

It doesn’t work. Is there a different setting I should do or is the shopping cart only item specific?

If it is, is there any way I can work around this to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you got to Promotions > Shopping Basket Rules > Then create new rule.

under conditions set the following:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : Total Items Quantity   `equals or greater than  5`

And second condition are TRUE : Total Items Quantity   `equals or less than  9` 
Then under actions:

for the Apply dropdown: choose `Percent product price discount` then below this add your percentage. like `5`

This is the basic requirement. There are more settings you can / tweak apply here.

i hope this can sure help you, and i just tested in my setup as you require.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried that and it didn't work for me. I think there's something I'm missing so I'll give it a try again. On a side note, what's the difference between the Conditions tab and the conditions in the Actions tab? I'm quite confuse with both.

Comment: in ur case there is no need to set action in action tab.I self tested in my magento version it is working very well.

Comment: this did not work at all. I already 6 different products in my cart (amount is 1 of each product) but nothing happened. But if I buy 5 of only 1 product, it works. I need to make it work both ways. (if I buy 5 items of the same product or if i buy 5 different products)

Comment: Please check with another setup of magento, or might be some other rules or code may be effect to your shopping cart.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much for your assistance. It works now, after taking a look at the guide you gave and the rule I had, I realized that there was a conflict between my settings under Conditions and Actions.