# Manipulating multiple shopping cart rules in Magento

Tags: magento

I have previously asked how to manipulate shopping cart rules when I had difficulty with it last time in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401781/manipulating-shopping-cart-rules). Now, I have added further conditions to my shopping cart rules.

To further explain, I have 2 shopping cart rules (get 5% off for every 5 items and get 10% off for every 10 items) and I have added 2 yes/no attributes corresponding to each shopping cart rule. The basic idea's like this:

> Shopping Cart Rule 1 = Yes/No Attribute 1
>
> Shopping Cart Rule 2 = Yes/No Attribute 2

If the yes/no attribute is set to yes, then the corresponding shopping cart rule should apply. The catch is, if I start mixing the cart rules, only the 5% discount applies properly. So if I enabled rule 1 and rule 2, only rule 1 would work properly rule 2 works when I buy 10 items but if I buy more, the discount disappears.

I'm not 100% certain if my conditions are right but here's the idea of how I've set it:

> Cart Rule 1:
>
> Apply cart rule if Yes/No 1 is Yes and Yes/No 2 is Yes and quantity >= 5 and quantity <= 9 or apply cart rule if Yes/No 1 is Yes and Yes/No 2 is No and quantity is >= 5
>
> Cart Rule 2:
>
> Apply cart rule if Yes/No 2 is Yes and quantity >= 10

So my question is, how can I mix the cart rules to work well with each other? I'm planning to add more rules. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in Cart rule 2 also , you should mention the condition like this :

Apply cart rule if Yes/No 1 is No and Yes/No 2 is Yes and quantity >=10 .

I think this will work. Just give a try.

Alternatively, please have a look at this link :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

Or you can make your work easy with the help of Magento's extension : MageTitan.
Here's a link for that : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magetitan-s-ultimate-cart-rules-7657.html

Thanks, 
Sweet72

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right, I needed to modify the condition of the second cart rule. After that, everything works awesome.