# Magento cart rules not being applied properly

Tags: php, magento

I have a rule in a store whereby shipping is free if the price is above £100. However, if there is a specific category i.e. `ID -> 10` then this rule cannot apply. Currently, this works if there is either only a category that cannot have free shipping or if there is only an item that can have free shipping in the cart. If there is both, it allows the free shipping anyway. So for example:

```
Category ID 1 has free shipping 
Category ID 2 Does not

If (ID contains 2) { Do not allow free shipping }
Else { Allow }
```

I have the rules set up to check to see if the product categories "contains" the ID not allowing free shipping. I have tried this is both the conditions and the actions submenus for shopping cart rules but it still seems to act in the following way:

```
if (contains 2) { Do not allow free shipping}
elseif ( contains 1 && 2 ) {allow free shipping}
else { Allow }
```

**Just to note** 
I have looked at pages such as these: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them 
 And 
[Manipulating multiple shopping cart rules in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534791/manipulating-multiple-shopping-cart-rules-in-magento) 
And still can't seem to come up with the solution. Thank you in advance for any help!